# Swift parsing nested datatype from Firebase Firestore using compactMapping

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to parse nested data types in Swift from Firestore with the document having the following structure:

```json
{
  date: 27 November 2021 at 00:00:00 UTC+13,
  item (map): {
          Ball: {
                 iNum: 12.99,
                 iP: 14252345,
                 iQ: 1
                 },
          RugbyBall: {
                 iNum: 12.99,
                 iP: 23425345,
                 iQ: 1
                  }
               }
}
```

And in swift I have the following structures:

```swift
struct mainStruct: Identifiable, Codable {
    @DocumentID var id: String? = UUID().uuidString
    var date: Date
    var items: itemListStruct
}

struct itemListStruct: Codable {
    var items: [itemStruct]
}

struct itemStruct: Identifiable, Codable {
    @DocumentID var id: String? = UUID().uuidString
    var iNum: Int
    var iP: Double
    var iQ: Int
}
```

As there could be a lot of documents with that format in the collection that I have attached a listener to I am trying to map them using compactMap like so:

```swift
self.items = documents.compactMap { (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> mainStruct? in
                return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: mainStruct.self)
            }
```

this method is similar to how the Firestore tutorial on Youtube works but for some reason the nested datatypes are causing it to fail. Is anyone able to work out why? It seems that I have created all the necessary structs for the different layers but it won't auto parse.

Comment: iNum is clearly not an integer

Comment: `return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: mainStruct.self)`: You are ignoring the error, it might tell you why it's failing... Use a proper do/try/catch.

Comment: Hi @mdav132, Is this issue resolved?

Comment: items should map/dictionary.   struct MainStruct: Identifiable, Codable {
    @DocumentID var id: String? = UUID().uuidString
    var date: Date
    var items: [String: ItemStruct]
}
PS: Watch the case when naming Class/Struct.